# Python compile with -Os flag on embedded arm linux completely unstable (shot in the dark >_<)

Tags: python, optimization, gcc, compiler-construction, arm

So I've been having problems with python segfaulting on an embedded system we're developing for. I can't for the life of me track down the problem. I recently tried a compile with the `-Os` switch on. This seems to have made things many, many times worse. I was just wondering if compiling with `-Os` was stupid in general, and if there was any success anyone else had with the `-Os` optimization.

I'm totally grasping at straws here to figure out this issue.

Comment: If `-Os` were _that_ badly broken, it'd probably be disabled or removed eventually. I know people who've used it well in the past, but always on desktop / server architectures. Can you reproduce the problem on other hardware?

Comment: "having problems with python segfaulting".  Too vague for anyone to understand the real problem.  "many, many times worse".  Largely meaningless without more details.  Further, which exact version of Python are you using.  `-Os` should (a) optimize and (b) change your sys.path.  You you really want to change the path?

Comment: The problem is too complex. "Having problems with python segfaulting" is pretty much all I can give you. It's happened on 2.6.5 and 2.7.1. What does `-Os` have to do with sys.path? @sarnold: I can barely reproduce the problem on my own platform. It's extremely intermittent.

Comment: **Where** does it segfault? Did you build it with debug info? Do you know how to use gdb?

Comment: @Igor Skochinsky: I've built python in probably 60 different ways. Yes with debug info (and both with, and without `Py_DEBUG`". The problem like I said is inconsistent. Not only with time, but with it's segfaulting. I'd say half the time it's in the `sem_wait` system function (although the rest of the trace is different). This tells me practically nothing though, since I assume the sem_wait is the global interpreter lock waiting. Other times, my frames look like this `#0  0x00000150 in ?? ()
#1  0x0016b0f0 in ?? ()
#2  0x0016b0f0 in ?? ()
`

Comment: @S.Lott Can you explain B? (-Os (optimize for small size) will change your sys.path)?

Comment: @Foon and @Falmarri: I've never seen `-Os`.  Only `-O` and `-O0`.  What **exact** version of Python is this?

Comment: There's more to your problem most likely than just the way you're compiling with Python. Take a step back and do some inventory on the situation. The important questions are: What toolchain are you using and what embedded distro framework? I'm guessing CodeSourcery and something OpenEmbedded based.. am I close?

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: "There's more to your problem most likely than just the way you're compiling with Python" Oh I know there definitely is. And I'm almost sure there's more than 1 problem. However, I've never seen any examples of -Os being used on the python interpreter, and I simply wanted to rule that out as A cause.

Comment: I'm running on an ARM PXA270 hydrogen board from boundary devices that has been heavily customized (not by us. Another company we work with). We have a custom built embedded kernel based on 2.6.30 with uBoot. Our toolchain is from boundary devices as well. We sort of inherited all of this low level work without TOO much experience in the embedded world.t

Comment: If you cat /proc/<PID_OF_PYTHON>/smaps, what does it say is mapped @ the point it crashes? Also, when you say it segfaults, does it happen when you run python (before it can do anything?) or does it run for a bit and then segfault?

Comment: Agree with @synthesizerpatel - start with a very basic program and eliminate the possibility of python/platform being to blame, then slowly add in complexity until it segfaults. I'd hate to be you right now :)

Comment: Maybe this is useful for you: http://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip/

Comment: @jozzas: It segfaults after an indeterminate period of time between 12 hours and never, with a different C stacktrace (from gdb), as well as a different python stacktrace (from pystack). It's not feasable to run a very basic program and see if it segfaults, as it almost certainly won't. It's some combination of our python code and the interpreter, build environment, and system hardware. I'm simply trying to eliminate possibilities at this point. @synthesizerpatel: I built every module that we need statically into the interpreter (the exception being _sqlite3.so) so the map tells me nothing.

Comment: I've closed this because it's just too vague. Feel free to update with more useful information (i.e. some pickings from the comments). Please don't make people guess or have extended discussions in the comments to try and find a way to help you.

Comment: I feel like my question wasn't too vague. Sure there's a lot of background and such. But the question was specific to if there are any know issues with compiling python with `-Os` flag